# Binary data written to a MySQL table via ODBC gets truncated

Tags: c++, mysql, odbc

I have a MySQL database with a table containing a `BINARY(16)` column.

When I write binary data via ODBC from my C++ application, the data is treated like a Null-terminated string, i.e. it is truncated at the first Null byte in the data.

In my C++ application I bind an `unsigned char [16]` array using `SQLBindParameter` like this:

```
SQLBindParameter(statementHandler, paramCount, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BINARY, SQL_BINARY, MAX_NOTIFICATION_OUT_IP_BIN_LEN, 0, _notificationOutDstIP, MAX_NOTIFICATION_OUT_IP_BIN_LEN, 0);
```

`MAX_NOTIFICATION_OUT_IP_BIN_LEN` is 16.

How can I make sure that 16 bytes are written to the database, even if the binary data contains Null values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MSDN documentation for `SQLBindParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710963.aspx):

> If `StrLen_or_IndPtr` is a null pointer, the driver assumes that all input parameter values are non-`NULL` and that character and binary data is null-terminated.

Instead, set that argument to be a pointer to the data length:

```
SQLBindParameter(statementHandler,
                 paramCount,
                 SQL_PARAM_INPUT,
                 SQL_C_BINARY, SQL_BINARY,
                 MAX_NOTIFICATION_OUT_IP_BIN_LEN,
                 0,
                 _notificationOutDstIP,
                 MAX_NOTIFICATION_OUT_IP_BIN_LEN,
                 &MAX_NOTIFICATION_OUT_IP_BIN_LEN
);
```

Comment: Obv, this assumes `MAX_NOTIFICATION_OUT_IP_BIN_LEN` is an `int` (`const` or otherwise); if it's a macro, you will first need to assign it to some variable which you reference.